# Cleaning data and removing brackets

Tags: php

Okay I have been having a little issue with the code below right now it pulls a bunch of data about a few stocks for me but I cant seem to get ride of the [ or ]. I thought it would be easy to remove the brackets by adding them to the end and the beginning of the preg_split but right when I do it just pops a error message.

Is there any command to remove all [ or all ] cause I know I have found a command in the past to remove all non numeric characters thank you so much btw

```
<?php
$Bloomberg = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/AAPL:US';
$Bloomberghtml = file_get_contents($Bloomberg);
$BloombergStart = preg_split('/data_values":/',$Bloomberghtml);
$BloombergRawData = preg_split('/>/',$BloombergStart[1]);

$OpenTimeStart = preg_split('/exch_open_time":/',$BloombergRawData[0]);
$OpenTime = preg_split('/,"/',$OpenTimeStart[1]);

$CloseTimeStart = preg_split('/exch_close_time":/',$BloombergRawData[0]);
$CloseTime = preg_split('/,"/',$CloseTimeStart[1]);

$StartPriceData = preg_split('/,/',$BloombergRawData[0]);


echo $BloombergRawData[0];
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo $OpenTime[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $CloseTime[0];
echo "<br>";

print_r($StartPriceData);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood your problem, but if you need to remove the '[' and ']' chars you can do that rather simply:

```
str_replace(array( '[', ']' ), '', $BloombergRawData);
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it should to the trick.